# How to select all elements between two h2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery. I have the following html fragment:

```
   <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>One header</h2>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>more text</p>
        <ul><li>a list</li></ul>
    <h2>Another header</h2>
        <a href="######">one link</a>
        <h3>ddd</h3>
        <p>eee</p>

    <h2>Header 3<h2>
    <p>This is a Paragraph</p>
```

I need to get the content that is between every h2 element, in order to do something like this:

```
First Section text

some text
more text

Second section text

one link
ddd
eee

Third section text
This is a Paragraph
```

I've read this resource:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm

but still cannot figure how to do what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the jQuery you have tried?

Comment: Try using [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/). Something like `$('h2').each(function() { console.log($(this).nextUntil('h2').text()); })`

Comment: Have you thought of giving each H2 a class and using .each()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('h2').each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        // gets everything between the $(this) and the next 'h2' element:
        contents = self.nextUntil('h2'),
        /* creates a new div with which to wrap,
           and inserts after the current $(this): */
        newWrap = $('<div />').insertAfter(self);
    // appends the contents to the new div element:
    newWrap.append(contents);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NhYX4/).

While the above works, for its intended use, and illustrates `nextUntil()` (which is definitely the method to use in this scenario), I'm unsure how I might show you how to achieve your aims, since you seem to have left your use-case/requirements rather vague.

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the nextUntil method is what you're looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to put the content you wish to retrive in a `<div>` tag with an id, and use jQuery to retrive it's content like so: `$('#divid').text()`

Comment: I agree with @cole-pileguard as his solution best answers your specific question.